# X axis date format using Flot, JSON, and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I generally bang my head against the wall until I can solve a problem using the collective wisdom of the internet but this time I'm stumped.  I hope someone can point out the stupid mistake I've made in a night's worth of fruitless effort.

I'm trying to produce a graph using Flotr using data from a MySQL database.  I've got it pretty well figured out but I can't seem to format the x-axis to display real times.  I can get the 13 digit UNIX time * 1000 there with no trouble but when I try to add the mode: "time" parameter to my $.plot statement all I get is a blank graph.  The source code in my browser looks about the same as what I get from the Flotr examples.  So here is my PHP database query:

```
        # issue statement
    $stmt = "SELECT T41,(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tstamp)*1000) AS tstamp "
        . " FROM tempLogExp ORDER BY tstamp DESC LIMIT 1440";
    $sth = $dbh->query ($stmt);

    while ($row = $sth->fetch (PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
    {
        $dServer[]=array(floatval($row['tstamp']),floatval($row['T41']));
    }
    $dbh = NULL;  # close connection
    ?>
```

And my Javascript looks like this:

```
$(function() {

        var d2 = <?php echo json_encode($dServer); ?>;

        $.plot("#placeholder", [d2], {
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time"
            }
        });

        // Add the Flot version string to the footer

        $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
    });
```

Commenting out the 'mode: "time"' line will make it produce a graph but with the line uncommented, as it is above, I just get a variegated rectangle.

I'm trying to graph 24 hours worth of data from some data loggers.  I'd appreciate a bit of help getting over this hurdle.

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: Just curious do you also have columns T00 through T40? Also, I wonder if this query executes faster... `$stmt = "
SELECT T41
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tstamp)*1000 tstamp 
  FROM tempLogExp x
 ORDER 
    BY x.tstamp DESC 
 LIMIT 1440;
";`

Comment: This database actually has columns T00 through T59 as well as a column with the time/date stamp and a serial number.  As it stands there are about 30,000 rows.  So far my queries using php don't cause any noticeable delay to the web page loading.

Comment: Step one has to be normalize your data.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually read the Flot documentation and found that I'd overlooked a plugin that was required for the 'mode: "time"' option to work.  Including "jquery.flot.time.js" solved my problem.